# Checking if Username exists not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, if-statement, mysqli

I believe that the issue has to do with `if(data == 1)` At the moment, the alert box keeps saying available and when i change it to `===`, and the alert box kept saying unavailable. I'm not exactly sure where the issue is.

This is my register.html

```
                    <form name="registerform" id="registerform" action="register.php" method="post">
                        <div class="form_settings">

                            <p>
                                <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
                                <input name="firstname" id="firstname" maxlength="32" type="text" placeholder="Optional" />
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="username" id="usernameText">Username:</label>
                                <input data-parsley-pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9_]{3,15}$" data-parsley-length="[3, 15]" name="username" id="username" maxlength="32" type="text" data-parsley-error-message="Username needs to be between 3 and 15 characters. Case sensitive. No special characters allowed." required/>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="password1">Password:</label>
                                <input name="password1" id="password1" data-parsley-pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9_-]{5,25}$" data-parsley-length="[5, 25]" type="password" data-parsley-equalto="#password2" data-parsley-error-message="Passwords must match. Needs to be between 5 and 25 characters. Case sensitive. No special characters allowed." required/>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="password2">Confirm Your Password:</label>
                                <input name="password2" id="password2" data-parsley-length="[5, 25]" data-parsley-error-message="Passwords must match. Needs to be between 5 and 25 characters. Case sensitive. No special characters allowed." data-parsley-pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9_-]{5,25}$" type="password" data-parsley-equalto="#password1" required/>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="email">E-Mail:</label>
                                <input data-parsley-trigger="change" name="email" id="email" maxlength="1024" type="email" required/>
                            </p>
                            <p style="padding-top: 15px"><span>&nbsp;</span>
                                <input type="submit" class="submit" name="createacc" value="Register" />
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Here is my javascript

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('input[name="createacc"]').click(function (e) {
                var username = $('input[name="username"]').val();
                if (username != '') {
                    e.preventDefault();


                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            username: username
                        },
                        url: 'checkuser.php',
                        success: function (data) { //Receives the data from the php code
                            if(data == 1){  
                                //show that the username is available  
                                alert("available");
                            }else{  
                                //show that the username is NOT available  
                                alert("Unavailable");
                            }  

                        },
                        error: function (xhr, err) {
                            console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                            console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                    $('#registerform').parsley();
                }
            });


        });
```

And here is my checkuser.php

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost");
define('DB_USER', "XXX");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "XXX");
define('DB_DATABASE', "XXX");   
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);    
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Connection Failed.";
    exit();
}
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);     
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT `username` FROM `accounts` WHERE username = '$username'");  
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){  
    echo json_encode(0);   
}else{  
    echo json_encode(1);  
}      
?>
```

**UPDATE**
I've tried all the suggestions that were posted in the comment section of this post and nothing has worked so far. Not sure what to do =/

Comment: In your **PHP** code you have to echo `1` (available) or something else (unavailable), I'm not sure if `json_encode(1)` send `1` or `"1"` or something completely diferent. If I'm wrong and `json_encode(1)` is ok, then make sure your **PHP** page is not sending **HTML** automatic code. To do that, you have to make sure that page just contains **PHP** code. Not: `<HTML><BODY><?PHP [code] ?></BODY></HTML>`.

Comment: @Verhaeren when I set it to `if(data === '"1"')` then the alert box keeps saying unavailable, if i set it to `if(data === "1")` the alert box keeps saying available

Comment: `var_dump(json_encode(1))` outputs `string(1) "1"`. So, your `if` statement should be something like `if (data == "1")` since it is a string.

Comment: @CEP That didn't work =/

Comment: @Verhaeren I change the echo code and it still didn't work. And when I changed it so `alert(data);` all i kept getting back was a 1.

Comment: @Verhaeren and when I removed the `if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)` and put `echo mysqli_num_rows($result);` nothing shows up in the alert box.

Comment: I am sure, as mentioned by @Verhaeren, you should actually check the Ajax output. See if you have `Fire Fox` and `Firebug` installed. Enable the console in firebug window, and then fire the even to see the response. I mean what you are getting from the server. I am sure the response in not `1` or `0`.

Comment: Would having `echo(mysqli_num_rows($result));` on my php form and then `console.log(data);` on my html form be a way of checking the ajax output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have an error in the returned string.

2 things: `mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters` and `mysqli_query() expects 2 parameters`.

Now both the methods expect 2 parameters, and as you've provided only one, so it returns the error string rather than `0` and `1`. So add your mysqli connection variable as the first parameter in both the methods. Here is the replacement code.

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['username']);     
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT `username` FROM `ncs_users` WHERE username = '$username'");
```

and try using [Parameterized](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) query instead of concatenating like what you did with `$username` in the query for security reasons.

Comment: I change those to what you said. What you're saying makes sense. But the alert box still saying Unavailable no matter what =/

Comment: Did you checked the output in `Firefox's firebug` console? On in case you are using `Google Chrome` then try it using inbuilt debugger. Which browser r u using?

Comment: I'm using chrome. And super stupid question. I'm not exactly sure how to use the debugger

Comment: Not an issue buddy :). Press `F12` while in your page, your window will get divided into 2 halfs. Select the `Network` tab. Then fire your event to let the console record the same. In the `Name Path` column select `checkuser.php`. Once clicked, on the right side you'll get the details. In this right panel, click the preview tab. If all is ok, you should see `0` or `1` as answer. Else some error string will be visible, to what I am 100% sure.

Comment: Wow You're honestly the best! Okay it currently said "1 No Properties" when I put in a username that is already registered it still says "1 No Properties" https://i.imgur.com/KtTnSb4.png

Comment: I bet you skipped the submit button press (I mentioned to fire the ajax call). You have to let the debugger see the firing of events

Comment: I did! checkuser.php didn't even show up until I fired the event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66802/discussion-between-cyberpks-and-dgameman1).

Answer (score 0):

you can return

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){  
    echo json_encode(array('vaild' => false));
die;   
}
else{  
    echo json_encode(array('vaild' => true));  
}
```

in javascript  set:

```
$.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            username: username
                        },
                        url: 'checkuser.php',
                        success: function (data) { //Receives the data from the php code
                            if(data.valid == true){  
                                //show that the username is available  
                                alert("available");
                            }else{  
                                //show that the username is NOT available  
                                alert("Unavailable");
                            }  

                        },
                        error: function (xhr, err) {
                            console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                            console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                    $('#registerform').parsley();
                }
            });
```

i hope this will help you.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier